# How can I include unnumbered chapters in a custom toc?

Tags: pdftex, table-of-contents

I'm trying to implement a custom toc in my Latex file and I would like to include the unnumbered chapter `Third Chapter`.

By the way, in the unnumbered chapter I would like to have the same structure but instead of having chapter 1 or 2 I would like to have just an empty rectangle with the same colour.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}

\newtcbox{\chapternumberbox}[1][]{%
  colback=darkmidnightblue!50!darkmidnightblue,
  colupper={white},
  colframe={white},
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  valign=center,
  size=small,
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  valign=center,
  interior style={left color={darkmidnightblue!30!darkmidnightblue},right color={darkmidnightblue!90!darkmidnightblue}},
  colframe={white},
  boxrule={1pt},
  colupper={white},
  size=small,
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}

\newcommand{\mychapternamebox}[3][]{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1]
    #2\hfill#3%
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername{} \thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={9.8cm}]{#1}{\thepage}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\chapter*{Third Chapter}
%\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{Second Chapter}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope you don't have more than 9 chapters or you will get in trouble with the way your "fancy toc" is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}

\newtcbox{\chapternumberbox}[1][]{%
  colback=darkmidnightblue!50!darkmidnightblue,
  colupper={white},
  colframe={white},
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  valign=center,
  size=small,
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  valign=center,
  interior style={left color={darkmidnightblue!30!darkmidnightblue},right color={darkmidnightblue!90!darkmidnightblue}},
  colframe={white},
  boxrule={1pt},
  colupper={white},
  size=small,
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}

\newcommand{\mychapternamebox}[3][]{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1]
    #2\hfill#3%
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername{} \thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={9.8cm}]{#1}{\thepage}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\chapter*{Third Chapter}
%\cleardoublepage
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\hphantom{Chapter 2}}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={9.8cm}]{Third Chapter}{\thepage}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: I really appreciate it

Comment: @THEWOLFSNOW You're welcome!

Comment: Can I ask you again please ? another issue is that the `hyperref` does not lead me to the right chapter (this is happening just for the unnumbered  chapters ) ?

Comment: My bad, it's working I just miss place it Thanks you